# Not able to connect MySQL database from angular

Tags: php, mysql, node.js, angular

Below is my AddUsersService class

```
        import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
        import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
        import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
        import { Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
        import { catchError, retry } from 'rxjs/operators'
        import { promise } from 'protractor';
        import { resolve } from 'url';
        import { User } from '../Models/user.model';

        @Injectable({
          providedIn: 'root'
        })
        export class AddUsersService {

        isLoggedIn = false;
        users: any;
        myPublisher = new Subject();
         
        constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
          console.log('AddUsersService const called');
            if (localStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn') === 'true') {
              this.isLoggedIn = true;
              this.myPublisher.next(true);
              
            }

        }

        getphp() {
          return new Promise((resolve) => {
             
             
             const myObservable = this.http.get('http://localhost:4200/assets/php/tmi_service.php');         
              myObservable.subscribe((res) => {
                  resolve(res);
              });
          });
        }
```

below is my UserComponent class, here i am calling the service method getphp but not able to call getting error below screen short

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { ClientService } from '../services/client.service';
    import { Router } from '@angular/router';
    import { NgForm, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
    import { User } from '../Models/user.model';
    import { Role } from '../Models/role.model';
    import { State } from '../Models/state.model';
    import { City } from '../Models/city.model';
    import { AddUsersService } from '../services/add-users.service';
    import { Project } from '../Models/project';
    import { Client } from '../Models/client.model';
     
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-user',
      templateUrl: './user.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./user.component.css']
    })
    export class UserComponent{

     
      submitted = false;
      selectedQuantity?: number
      selectedQuantity1?: number
      selectedQuantity2?: number
      msg?: string
      unexist?: string
     
     
      constructor(private userSvc: AddUsersService,private route: Router) {
    
         this.userSvc.getphp().then((data: Client[]) => {
          //this.list = data;
          console.log(data);
      });
   
      }
    }
```

[image]

I have added php file into angular project in assets/php/tmi_service.php

```
<?php
$servername = "172.20.3.22";
$username   = "mazhar";
$password   = "Tech#123";
$dbname     = "tmivirtualdashboard";
$SslMode = "None";
$port = "3306";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname,$SslMode,$port);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    }
    
 //   echo "Connected successfully";
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM Clients";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    $myArray = array();
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $myArray[] = $row;
    }
    print json_encode($myArray);
    }
    else
    {
    echo "0 results";
    }
    
?>
```

I am not able to fetch data from mysql database please help i am facing this issue since one week but still on the same place.

below example i am referring, and new to php, i am dot net developer first time doing php kind of thing

https://therichpost.com/angular-8-with-mysql-database-working-example/

Comment: Look like your webserver did not execute PHP code but returning the source code, please check your webserver configuration, make sure its config is correct

Comment: how to configuration for web-server in angular. @catcon

Comment: What's your webserver? apache? nginx?

Comment: i m new to php  and added php file directly into angular project in assets/php/tmi_service.php and  i refer this ex https://therichpost.com/angular-8-with-mysql-database-working-example/.

Comment: I am not using any webserver. @caton

Comment: The link you provide use `XAMPP` to install apache, php and mysql to your machine. Google "install xampp", there are plenty tutorials that you can follow.

Comment: I am using mysql workbench database, shall i have to install xampp also, can we chat now. @catcon

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218865/discussion-between-mohd-mazhar-khan-and-catcon).